# After Installing NetBeans 8.0.2 with GlassFish 4.1 Cannot Connect to sample Database

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, glassfish

I installed NetBeans 8.0.2 with glassfish-4.1.  The sample folder is present under C:\Users\Username.netbeans-derby.  When I bring up NetBeans and go to the Services tab the connection to sample is present: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample [app on APP] but sample is not listed under Java DB so when I try to connect to sample I get the following error "Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost1527/sample using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (The connection was refused becuase the database sample was not found)."

Answer (score 0):

Right click on `Java DB` select `Create Database`.

- use as `Database Name` 'sample'
- use as `User Name` 'app'
- leave the password empty

**edit**
Seems there is a broken database or maybe one from an earlier Netbeans installation. Remove the `sample` connection in Netbeans and remove the directory `%USERPROFILE%\.netbeans-derby\sample`. Recreate the `sample` database as described above.

Comment: I entered 'sample' for Database Name and got the error message "The database location already contains the file named sample" and could not proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had both NetBeans 8.0.1 and 8.0.2 installed, so maybe that confused things.  Because of what you stated in your comment, I uninstalled both versions then re-installed version 8.0.2 and everything was okay.

Answer (score 0):

I had a broken database from an earlier version too, and then couldn't connect to the sample db.
I simply had to delete the .netbeans-derby directory, 
then reinstalled Netbeans,
and is was ok, then.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me and re-installing NetBeans did not help.  After poking around the databases for a bit, I finally got mine working using the following process.

1. Create a new database with any properties (i.e. name, user, pw)
2. Navigate to your user directory \.netbeans-derby\{name}\
3. Copy service.properties file and paste in \.netbeans-derby\sample\
4. Reconnect to sample database in NetBeans

A couple extra notes:

- If you configured your NetBeans database to a different location, use that location in step 2.
- You may need to delete and re-create the existing sample database connection in NetBeans for it to pickup the new service.properties file.